# Do not match if nothing exists between optional parenthesis

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to parse group names from /etc/security/login-access.conf. We have a mixed environment of LDAP & AD machines. AD groups are encapsulated with parenthesis ().

I have the following regex that works to extract only the group name, however the only problem I am having with it is there is routinely a 'null' group and the regex returns a null & the ) characters:

Current regex:

```
/(?<=\+\s:\s[@\(])(.*?)(?=[\)]?\s:)/
```

Sample /etc/security/login-access.conf:

```
+ : @ldapgroup1 : ALL
+ : @ldapgroup2 : ALL
+ : (@adgroup1) : ALL
+ : (@adgroup2) : ALL
+ : () : ALL          # <---This is the problematic entry.
```

I'm not sure if or how to tune the regex to ignore an entry that contains nothing between the parenthesis. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply match what you are looking for? `(?<=\@)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` captures all alphanumeric chars and dashes that follow the `@` sign. What do you want for a no-match? Default is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your regex engine appears to have capture groups, I would just express your pattern as:

```regex
\+ : (\(@\S+\)|@\S+) : \S+
```

### Demo

Here I use an alternation to cleanly match either the parentheses or non parentheses variants of the LDAP group names.

Comment: The current regex I am using strips the parenthesis & @ symbols; I'd like to maintain that behavior. The results from this list are compared against LDAP queries to identify membership status between /etc/security/login-access.conf and directory services.

Comment: Does your regex tool/language not support capture groups?  The version I gave above is much cleaner.

Comment: Yes I'm using perl, however the results in the capture groups in the above example return @ldapgroup1 & (@adgroup1). I'm trying to have the results be ldapgroup1 & adgroup1. I just can't find a way around that () : ALL line...

Comment: You can just call sub and trim off the leading/trailing parentheses.  The problem with your current approach is that it would also match something like `(@adgroup1`, with a missing right parenthesis.

Comment: I may end up having to do that, I'm not a regex pro by any stretch; so I'm trying to learn what I can/cannot do with regex before resulting to other means.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most efficient, definitely ugly but it works:

`(?<=\+\s:\s@|\()([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(?=[\)]?\s:)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using perl, you can use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
\+\h:\h(?|@([\w-]+)|\(@([\w-]+)\))\h:
```

The pattern matches:

- `\+\h:\h` Match  `+` and a colon between horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `@([\w-]+)` Match `@` and capture 1+ word chars or a hyphen in **group 1**
  - `|` Or
  - `\(@([\w-]+)\)` Match `(@`, capture capture 1+ word chars or a hyphen in **group 2** *(which will be available in group 1 due to the branch reset group)* and match `)`
- `)\h:` Close branch reset group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lUDWdo/1)